# How can i compare two arrays and add unique records to the table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to compare and add unique records From TABLE B to TABLE A and skips the duplicate records if exist and perform the search on the next record, if it doesn't find a match, then add it. 
***compare using [SalesDescription] field***

i tried using array_unique and array_differ, array_intersect but none of these functions cant get rid of the duplicates/ cant work for me.

Here is the code adds data

```
  $records=array(
      'SalesDescription'         => $row['SalesDescription'],
      'SO Qty' => $row['Quantity'],
      'WO Qty'          => $row['Reference'],
      'SO Date'          => $row['TransactionDate'],
      'Color'         => $row['DistNumber'], 
      'SO#'         => $row['Reference'], 
      'Promised Date'         => $row['GoodThruDate'], 



     );

    $tv->addRecord($tableId, $records);//calls addRecord() function
```

Table A: record from the table where i would like to add data into

```
Array ( 
      [id] => 3054535376 
      [table_id] => 50240233993 
      [created] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
      [updated] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
      [created_by] => 3045444045538 
      [fields] => Array ( 
                        [Work Order] => 87565 
                        [SalesDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
                        [SO#] => 14061 
                        [SO Date] => 2013-10-16T00:00:00-0600 
                        [Promised Date] => 2014-10-30T09:52:15-0600 
                        [SO Qty] => 1.0000000000000000000 
                        [WO Qty] => 14061 
                        [Color] => 2 
                        [s] => 2 
                        [SHIP BY] => 2014-10-29 
                        [CALC PROMISED DATE] => 2014-10-30 
                        ) 
   )
```

Table B: record from the table where i would like to get data from

```
 Array ( 
       [0] => CAS001 
       [CustomerId] => CAS001 
       [1] => CASH CUSTOMER 
       [Customer_Bill_Name] => CASH CUSTOMER 
       [2] => Will Call 
       [WhichShipVia] => Will Call 
       [3] => [INV_POSOOrderNumber] => [4] => 2013-07-24 
       [ShipByDate] => 2013-07-24 
       [5] => [GoodThruDate] => [6] => [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 13867 
       [Reference] => 13867 [8] => 2013-07-24 
       [TransactionDate] => 2013-07-24 
       [9] => 1 
       [DistNumber] => 1 
       [10] => 2.0000000000000000000 
       [Quantity] => 2.0000000000000000000 
       [11] => 121130581 
       [ItemId] => 121130581 
       [12] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
       [SalesDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFT TIRE PRESS-ONS 
       [13] => [PartNumber] => [14] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFTTIRE 
       [ItemDescription] => 18X5X12 1/8 SOLID FORKLIFTTIRE
       )
```

Comment: Both array fields are different and I believe that you are comparing a particular field value in both array, then you simply check if(a.field.salesDescription == b.salesDescription) ?

Comment: @Asik Thanks!!. It does work partially but when i run the PHP script again it creates duplicate record

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit a hassle, but you can first create an array with keys (namely the SalesDescription values).
Double SalesDescription will overwrite eachother, and afterward you convert it back:

```
<?php

$tableB = array(....)

$temp = array();
foreach($tableB as $value) {
  $temp[$value['SalesDescription']] = $value;
}
$tableB = array();
foreach($temp as $value) {
  $tableB[] = $value;
}

// Now $tableB has only unique SalesDescription's!
```

Comment: Michiel, Thank for the reply but i want to compare/search the value [SalesDescription] field on table A and table B. if there is a match on Table A skips it and do the next search/compare but i think in your case it compare only [SalesDescription] field on table B. the thing is i want to run the PHP script every 10 minutes to add new record from table B to A.

Comment: Ah okay, but are you still only comparing the SalesDescription field? Or are there more fields that make a row unique?

Comment: Thanks again Michiel, yes will be more field but right now I want to test it with SalesDescription field?